# Validating more than one field on a form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a registration form and I want to validate that the password and email fields by adding confirm fields for each. Both field must be validated before clicking on the submit button. Is there a way to validate both email and password fields on the same form. Below is what i have for my password fields which works great but i need help to validate the email section too on the same form. thanks in advance

```
<Form>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required  />
<input type="email" name="confirm_email" id="confirm_email" placeholder="Confirm Email" required /> 

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Company name" required />

<input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" onkeyup='check();' />
<input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password"  onkeyup='check();' /> 
<span id='message'></span>
</Form>

<script>
var check = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('password').value ==
    document.getElementById('confirm_password').value) {
    document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'green';
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Password match confirmed';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Please confirm your password.';
  }
}</script>
```

Comment: What do you want to trigger the other validation? Presumably you don't want it to check the email when someone enters the password and vice versa, so when is this to execute?

Comment: For starters, storing check in a `var` is going to be a problem, since that variable is undefined above. Make it `function check(){`. Then you write code. Of course, I really recommend external JavaScript with the tags in your `<head>` and use `addEventListener('load', ()=>{ /* now do stuff */ }`.

Comment: @ FluffyKitten I want to check and vailidate email first and display the match confirmed message before moving onto the password field

Comment: OP lacks effort to even try what OP asks for. -1

Comment: ....and you want to do that in one function only ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping No please

Comment: ....then Just create another function and copy the same code you have above and change the `password` to `email` - what do you want to do other then that ?

Comment: I tried that but Validation works for the email field only

Comment: You still want a solution for this ? You always want to validate the email first correct ?

Comment: Yes please. Email first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for the `attributes` using [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) on where which input is being `typed` in and then from their you can do the `validation` of your `email` first.

Also, to make sure that `email` is always getting `confirmed` first we need to set a global `variable` which is initially `false` but as soon the email is confirmed it becomes `true` and then you can move on to the password `feilds`.

If you directly goes towards the `password` the input you will see the message that *please verify you `email` first*.

Lastly, i have cleaned up your and is simplified the `code` as well by declaring the `inputs` as `variable` so that we can use them again in our `code` if needed. I have also added when input field must not be **empty** when doing the `validation` of fields.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
var emailConfirmed = false
var message = document.getElementById('message')
var email = document.getElementById('email')
var confEmail = document.getElementById('confirm_email')
var password = document.getElementById('password')
var confPassword = document.getElementById('confirm_password')

function check(e) {
  if (e.getAttribute('id') == 'email' || e.getAttribute('id') == 'confirm_email') {
    if (email.value != '' && confEmail.value != '' && email.value == confEmail.value) {
      message.style.color = 'green';
      message.innerHTML = 'Email match confirmed';
      emailConfirmed = true
    } else {
      message.style.color = 'red';
      message.innerHTML = 'Please confirm your email.';
      emailConfirmed = false
    }
  }

  if (e.getAttribute('id') == 'password' || e.getAttribute('id') == 'confirm_password') {
    if (emailConfirmed) {
      if (password.value != '' && confPassword.value != '' && password.value == confPassword.value) {
        message.style.color = 'green';
        message.innerHTML = 'Password match confirmed';
      } else {
        message.style.color = 'red';
        message.innerHTML = 'Please confirm your password.';
      }
    } else {
      message.style.color = 'red';
      message.innerHTML = 'Please confirm your email first.'
    }
  }
}
```

```css
input {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" onkeyup='check(this);' required />
  <input type="email" name="confirm_email" id="confirm_email" placeholder="Confirm Email" onkeyup='check(this);' required />


  <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" onkeyup='check(this);' />
  <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" onkeyup='check(this);' />

  <br>
  <span id='message'></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much